# Check if value is of primitive type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a method:

`deepCopy (destination: any, source: any {...}`

and I would like to check if the `source` is of any primitive type in ExtJS it would look like `Ext.isPrimitive(source)` but I can't find a way to do it in TypeScript.

Comment: Same as a js solution

Comment: @NitzanTomer Primitive is not a type(?) i can't to `source instanceof primitive` or `typeof source  == 'primitive'`.

Comment: In js (and then in ts as well), a value can be either a primitive or an object. You can take one of the ways described in the answers to the duplicated question and just negate it to get a `isPrimitive` function.

Comment: Do you mean check at compile time or run time? If the former, why not just declare the function as `deepCopy(destination: any, source: object)` and let TypeScript do the checking?

Comment: @Aernor `obj && typeof yourVariable !== 'object'` should be good as a `isPrimitive` function. I don't understand what the definition of the typescript `object` type has to do with this